# Connect webcam to android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, webcam

I have been trying to make the camera work on the emulator with no success. My emulator has the following characteristics (`config.ini`):

```
Name: Samsung_Tablet_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Alvaro\.android\avd\Samsung_Tablet_API_23.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: 2560x1600

SD Card: C:\Users\Alvaro\.android\avd\Samsung_Tablet_API_23.avd\sdcard.img

hw.lcd.density: 280

hw.dPad: no

hw.initialOrientation: landscape

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera=yes

hw.camera.back=webcam0

hw.camera.front=webcam0

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard.lid: yes

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:117408129c6b5b94ffcdb00df3e428c8

hw.ramSize: 1536

tag.id: google_apis

tag.display: Google APIs

hw.device.manufacturer: User

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.mainKeys: yes

skin.path.backup: _no_skin

hw.accelerometer: no

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: Samsung Tablet

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.battery: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: no

AvdId: Samsung_Tablet_API_23

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.sensors.orientation: no

hw.camera.front: webcam0

hw.gps: no

avd.ini.displayname: Samsung Tablet API 23

vm.heapSize: 64

image.androidVersion.api: 23

runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

The error I get everytime I try to open the camera is the following:

> Camera error: Can't connect to the camera

I have properly created the emulator (at least I think!) given that every time i launch it the following screen appears:

[image]

Futhermore I have updated all the drivers for the webcam and it's perfectly working for other software...

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect my webcam with an emulator by adding following lines to my `config.ini` :

```
hw.camera=yes
sdcard.size=100M
```

I do not see any `sdcard.size` in your config